# Working around encoding issues on Windows with .m3u files

Tags: ubuntu-one

I'm syncing .mp3 files with UTF-8 filenames and .m3u playlists referencing these filenames -- generated on an Ubuntu system -- to a Windows machine.  .mp3 filenames appear correctly in the Windows explorer, but when trying to play a .m3u playlist with Windows Media Player, it shows broken filenames and skips over files with non-ASCII characters.

I guess the filenames are stored in another encoding than UTF-8 on Windows, which Ubuntu One doesn't really care about, but the contents of the .m3u files aren't translated.

I'm looking for suggestions in dealing with this!  :-)

Thanks!

-- 
Loïc Minier

Comment: Creating a .wpl file with the playlist worked; I copy-pasted the model from:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Player_Playlist
and it worked with UTF-8 encoded filenames (since encoding of XML is well defined).

Another option is to use more tolerant software such as VLC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your music player on windows is opening the `.m3u` in something other than UTF-8. From searching around a little, it seems that if the extension is `.m3u8`, things will just work.

What's more, the [Wikipedia article on M3U](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) says that the encoding has to be Latin-1 if the extension is `.m3u`, and that you have to use `.m3u8` for UTF-8 encoded filenames.

Also, as you [lool](https://askubuntu.com/users/25941/lool) pointed out "[c]reating a `.wpl` file with the playlist worked; I copy-pasted the model from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Player_Playlist and it worked with UTF-8 encoded filenames (since encoding of XML is well defined). Another option is to use more tolerant software such as VLC."

Comment: Unfortunately, WMP doesn't recognize .m3u8 nor .pls files; drag-n-drop such a file to WMP and it wont add them to the queue, and by default these aren't associated to WMP either.

Comment: Interestingly, VLC takes the .m3u with UTF-8 filenames just fine under Windows.